# pesquisa em php passar para html

Tags: php, html

Bom dia pessoal.

Estou precisando muito da ajuda de vcs. Estou com um problema a dias em uma página html na qual pego 3 dados para pesquisa no banco. Até aí tudo bem. Conecto no banco, e tenho o retorno da pesquisa corretamente via busca.php, mas, os dados que estão em busca.php não consigo passar para o html. A execução para no php e aparecem em uma pagina em branco, não retornando para a página em html.

*** trecho do código em index.html: ***

```
<select name="selsegmento" class="custom-select">

<option selected>Segmento</option>

<option value=""></option>

<option value="2">Restaurante</option>

<option value="3">Serviços Manuais</option>

</select> 
outro select...

<button type="submit" id="Buscar">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
```

*** trecho do codigo de busca.php: ***

Dados da busca:

```
<?php
    if (count($resultado) > 0){
?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> segmento  </th>
            <th> nome </th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            foreach ($resultado as $res) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$res['seg_nome'];?></td>
            <td><?=$res['nome_nome'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php } else {?>
    <h3> Dados não encontrados </h3>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você pode postar todo o seu código? O que seria essa variável $resultado?

Comment: Bom dia Angelo. Não postei mais pelo código ser bem grande. $Resultado é o resultado do sql, o qual tem as linhas com os dados que tenho que colocar na tela. Até aí está correto, por isso também não coloquei este trecho do código.

Comment: As chavetas deste else `<?php } else {?>` esta a ser fechadas? acessa a pagina e clica em `ver fonte da pagina` ve se tem algum erro embutido no final do codigo-fonte.

Answer (score 0):

O código completo nos ajudaria a entender melhor. Uma tentaria seria substituir o código abaixo: (é o único trecho publicado que contém short tags, se não estiver exibindo esta parte, pode ser a solução)

```
        <td><?php echo $res['seg_nome'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['nome_nome'];?></td>
```